# Node-red dashboard label translation

Tags: internationalization, translation, dashboard, multilingual, node-red

Using node-red-dashboard with Node-red what is the best way to have a multi-language dashboard?

[image: Label]

With a "Node" there is a way to use data-n18n attribute and the locales directory in a node to translate texts. How can this be done with flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for internationalization of the node-red-dashboard.

For further discussion on the subject, I suggest you follow up on the project mailing list or slack team, linked to on https://nodered.org